# Trouble changing css `top` value to fixed element with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to move a `position:fixed` div on scroll by changing the `top:` css value in javascript. The div won't move though, not sure why.

html:

```
<div id="red">
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#red {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: solid 2px #f0f;
}

#blue {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  border: solid 2px #0ff;
}
```

js:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var yPos = -(Math.floor(document.body.scrollTop / 10));
  //console.log("yPos = " + yPos); //output is correct
  document.getElementById('blue').style.top = yPos + 'px';
  //document.getElementById('blue').setAttribute('top',yPos); //also tried this
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akzx43yL/

Why isn't the `top` css value changing and how can I get it to do so? No jquery please.

Comment: First off you definitely want to debounce your scroll event or you're browser will likely break out a sweat, next why don't you just change from position fixed to absolute when you start scrolling?

Comment: `= yPos + 'px';`

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/sjac0w67/ . Seems like the `.style.top = yPos` in the js isn't actually having any effect regardless of the position style of the element.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, adding to question, but still no cigar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- Instead of `document.documentElement.scrollTop`, you should use **[`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset)** (`scrollTop` doesn't play nicely in Chrome).
- You need to add a unit of measurement after you update `top`; values other than `0` should have `px` appened to them.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var yPos = -(Math.floor(window.pageYOffset / 10));
  document.getElementById('blue').style.top = yPos + "px";

  // Optionally log the `top` value
  //console.log(document.getElementById('blue').style.top);
});
```

```css
#red {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: solid 2px #f0f;
}

#blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  border: solid 2px #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't look like `blue` is moving 10 times slower than scroll speed as described here: `window.pageYOffset / 10`... or am I missing something? See: https://jsfiddle.net/vptjxdyo/

Comment: Your `top` value is still zero in your example. Your line of code `document.getElementById('blue').style.top += yPos + 'px'` won't work; you can't do addition with strings. Simply remove the `+` before the `=`; the value is updated automatically anyway :)

Comment: Okay but why isn't this working then: https://jsfiddle.net/200xjj8j/ ? Notice how the blue element does not scroll 1000 times slower than the red here... instead it scrolls normally as any `absolute`ly positioned element would without any js.

Comment: You can't divide by `1000`. I'm not really sure why, but that still doesn't update the top value. If you take the exact same code in your fiddle, and divide by `10` instead of `1000`, it will work. Though note that you probably want to increase the value rather than decrease it :)

Comment: Oooooooh lol I thought dividing by 1000 would make it more noticeable for some reason. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

If you check your console, you will be see your `console.log("yPos = " + yPos)` is always 0 you most update your code as follow:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var yPos = -(Math.floor(document.documentElement.scrollTop / 10));
    console.log("yPos = " + yPos);
    document.getElementById('blue').style.top = yPos + "px";
});
```

**Tip**:

Ways to get srollTop (pure js):

```
var top  = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
document.getElementById('blue').style.top = yPos + "px";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).